# How to deploy a HTML5 website as a mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, html, mobile

I have a server hosting a website that is HTML5 compatible.  I can access the site from my android phone via chrome just fine but i don't want the app to look as if its running within a chrome browser.  I want it to look like a stand alone application.

I've taken a peak at Cordova, and PhoneGap but it just feels like what i'm trying to do should be much simpler and without need of a framework so to speak.

How can i package my website for delivery to android/ios so it runs without look like it is inside the native browser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On Android there is Progressive Web Apps
https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/

Other than that you'll have to use a framework to make real apps like the one you mentioned.